# Not understand foreign key structure

Tags: mysql

[image]
[image]
[image]
Can someone explain to me what is the meaning of picture above?

The part `FOREIGN KEY (staffID, workload) REFERENCES table_lecturerdetails (staffID, workload)`?

I created the third table need data from table_lecturerdetails and table_staffdetails. 
The part `FOREIGN KEY (staffID, workload) REFERENCES table_lecturerdetails (staffID, workload)` is correct? Since my tabel_lecturerdetails got staffID and workload as PK but the sql there i only write workload , even i refer to workload and staffID in table_lecturerdetails.

Comment: I think you need to read up on some tutorials again, a good source to get easy explanation with examples. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I got 1 table name staffID as primary key, another table name lecturerdetails with staffID,workload as primary key, when i create the third table need foreign key from lecturer details, i used workload as my attribute, is that correct?

Comment: Can you show your code? I can't understand what you are asking. Or please make it little clearer.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you explain a little clearly?

Comment: Is it clear now? my workload attribute in third table can represent staffID and workload PK from table_lecturerdetails?

Comment: I think I understand, To use a compound Primary Key as Foreign Key, you'll have to add the same number of columns (that compose the PK) with same datatypes to the child table and then use the combination of these columns in the FOREIGN KEY definition:

Comment: You got me. So, is it my written code is correct? I mean that attribute of workload.

Comment: Have you tried to insert anything into the tables?

Comment: So far haven't, will try it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you try something before asking a question on Stack. It makes things easier in helping you. If my answers help you tomorrow, let me know. I will update it once you confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `foreign keys` on tables tells the table for the value that must be there and other than that, if you try to insert something in the foreign key table. You will get a  `DataIntegrityConstraint` Violation.

Answer (score 0):

A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

```
Can someone explain to me what is the meaning of picture above? the part FOREIGN KEY (staffID, workload) REFERENCES table_lecturerdetails (staffID, workload)?
```

The staffID and workload are columns in your lecturedetails table which are PK, and you are pointing to them within the image above as FK. When inserting you need to be sure that value you enter is present in lecturedetails.